# How to add list to the loaded template in phpword

Tags: php, yii, phpword, yii1.x

I used PHPword to create a word document in my web application but I coud not implement list. I used the following code:

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$temp = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('temp.docx');
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
$section->addListItem('List Item 1', 0);
$section->addTextBreak(1);
$temp->setValue('Value1', $section);
$temp->save('list.docx');
```

This code is not working. I managed to create a list in a new document but I could not add the list to the template (I could not assign a list to the specific value). How can I add the list?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: if i do not add $section to $temp->setValue , it will work

Comment: If I add $section to $temp->setValue, it will show empty page.(Headers do not work)

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560142/manipulating-template-in-phpword

Comment: what is your expected value in $section with this line $temp->setValue('Value1', $section);

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301938/how-to-add-list-to-the-loaded-template-in-phpword#comment75857849_44301938), a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15392307/5012320) addressed your question.

Basically, you cannot provide a `section` object as the second parameter of the `setValue` method as it expects a string value for this parameter.

You may want to add the function described in the above previous answer to the Template.php file in the PHPWord directory to accomplish the functionality you are looking for.